# Custom Role accessing the wp-option table

Tags: user-roles, options

I'm using a plugin that create an additional record in the wp-option. Everything is great with the admin account, the record can be save and update. But I'm stuck with allowing one of the custom role I have made. I want to enable these role to do the same as well. I have try the "manage_options" but no luck. I think I might have miss something very simple. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Please add the code of how option table item is saved and updated. In which page user can do that? Please describe in more details.

Comment: Hi @sakibmoon, I was using this [plugin](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/). This is for the custom tax meta field. So these field appear in my custom tax. From looking at the code it is using the update_option to store the data in the wp-option table. So I think it has something to do with the capability for my custom role to access that wp_option table.

Answer (score 0):

I sort out the problem now. It seem that the permission for 'manage_categories' is needed for this plugin.